# memory location of java.lang.Class object

Tags: java

In JVM's memory there are two areas: 
Method Area
Heap
Whenever a class is loaded its information is I think kept in the Method Area. Also I think an object of java.lang.Class is created for each loaded class. Where is this object stored ? Is it stored in Heap or Method Area ? Is it subjected to Garbage Collection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Stack section` of memory contains methods, local variables and reference variables.

The `Heap section` contains Objects (may also contain reference variables)

Static methods (in fact all methods) as well as static variables are stored in the `PermGen` section of the heap.

```
Is it stored in Heap or Method Area ? Is it subjected to Garbage Collection ?
```

Yes.! It is stored in Heap. All the objects are stored in Heap.

For more [Details click!!](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html)

Comment: +1 The Class is a proxy of the class information which is stored in the PermGen, BTW in Java 8, the PermGen is going away and this data will be also stored on the heap.